Umbraco 14 Can't login to back office - This server only accepts HTTPS requests
I recently upgraded my Umbraco installation to version 14 and encountered an issue after deploying to Azure. The front end of the website works fine over HTTPS, but when I navigate to /umbraco to log in, I encounter the following error:
error:invalid_request
error_description:This server only accepts HTTPS requests.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2083

I have verified that my website is indeed using HTTPS both locally and on Azure. When running locally via Visual Studio (IIS Express), I do not encounter this problem. However, after deploying to my local IIS or Azure, I consistently see this error.
Before the upgrade to Umbraco 14, everything worked correctly on my local IIS. Could you please advise on what might have changed in Umbraco 14 regarding HTTPS enforcement, and what steps I can take to resolve this issue?
By the way my Umbraco Website is running inside a docker container, and running on Azure. I don't know if that makes any diffrence or not.

Please try add this on program.cs
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCertificateForwarding();

